# mysql between condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand a portion of a query i am looking at. it was written elsewhere.

`between now() - interval 30 day and now();`

Does this mean between now and 30 days above (returns data between now and one month in advance or does it mean between now and one month prior?

The problems i am having to understand are:

- Why is there a minus sign instead of an AND after between? Unless the and condition is (between now-interval 30 day AND now).
- If so, does the minus sign incinuate back 30 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesis will probably help:

```
col BETWEEN (now() - interval 30 day) AND now()
```

`now() - interval 30 day` means "30 days ago" - the whole expression is "between 30 days ago and now". Actually, unless you have values higher than current datetime, you can simply use:

```
col >= NOW() - interval 30 day
```

[This page](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/) is a good explanation of the `INTERVAL` syntax. MySQL documentation about time and date functions `DATE_ADD()` and `DATE_SUB()` explains the syntax as well: [Date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

`now() - interval 30 day` is equivalent to `date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)`, so you could also write the condition like this:

```
col BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) AND now()
```

Note that `NOW() - interval 30 day` means 30 days ago at this exact time, because `NOW()` returns a `DATETIME` value.